# $(document).ready not called in brunch/jade/backbone project

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, pug, document-ready, brunch

I have a project with brunch/jade/backbone that uses an index.html file which calls in everything using backbone, and jade.

index.html (parts):

```
<html>
<head>
  [...]
  <script type="text/javascript" src="data/vendor.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="data/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="data/data.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    require('initialize');
  </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

The vendor.js file includes the generated (using brunch) jquery.js, backbone.js, and other libraries I need there. So it is included *before* usin the script.

My layout.jade:

```
body
  [blah...blah]

  script(src="data/credentials.js")
```

data/credentials.js:

```
var username="blah";
var password="bluh";

// alert("test");
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#credentials").html(
    '<div class="username">' + username + '<div>' + 
    '<div class="password">' + password + '<div>' + 
    );
});
```

I see that the js file is included in the final html file, but the *ready* function is never executed, whatever I tried. Funnily, if I uncomment the alert, I see no popup neither.

So why is this file found, loaded, but does not execute? I thought each js file that is loaded within an html file is executed there? So the *alert* function should fire, shouldn't it?
What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Is jQuery included, did it load correctly?

Comment: jQuery is included correctly, and BEFORE this script.

Comment: Er, why exactly is this question downvoted?

Comment: and a simple alert should have nothing to do with a JQuery.

Comment: Try looking in your console to see if username or password is defined. Since you say the alert is never shown, I'm guessing the script is never loaded.

Comment: that's what I suppposed as well. A simple `print("username");` should do, right? This says `ReferenceError: username is not defined`. Which means that it was not loaded, right?

Comment: Oh, and using Firefox/Debugger/Sources, I don't see credentials as file there. = not loaded... hmmmm

Comment: Ah. found it. When opening the **file** index.html in the folder (which is my targeted behaviour in production) - the js file is found, loaded, everything is ok. when serving from localhost:3333 using brunch, the file is not found because at the URL data/credentials.js is nothing served ;-)  It worked just the first time when I called the index.html in a folder instead of using the built-in server...

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick since you didnt include any JQuery.

```
window.onload('Example');

function Example()
{
document.getelementbyid(credentials).innerHtml = 
'<div class="username">' + username + '<div>' + 
    '<div class="password">' + password + '<div>';

}
```

Comment: JQuery is included, should have mentioned it. If not, I would get an error message, that $ is undefined....